# Laravel 5.4+ : Mutator/Accessor for uploaded image

Tags: php, laravel-5, model, accessor, mutators

I'm trying to use mutator to store and retrieve users gravatar.

In my User model I have :

```
public function getGravatarAttribute($gravatar){
    if($gravatar){
        $image = Storage::disk('local')->get('public/avatars/'.$gravatar.'.jpg');
        return new Response($image, 200);
    }

    $hash = md5(strtolower(trim($this->attributes['email'])));
    return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/$hash?s=256";
}


public function setGravatarAttribute($gravatar){
    if(is_object($gravatar) && $gravatar->isValid()){
        $image = Image::make($gravatar)->fit(256, 256);
        Storage::disk('local')->put('public/avatars/'.$this->id . '.' . $gravatar->getClientOriginalExtension(),  $image->response());
        $this->attributes['gravatar'] = $this->id;
    }
}
```

In the Blade file I do :

```
<img id="avatar" src="{{ $user->gravatar }}" alt="your image" width="256" height="256"/>
```

The mutator works nicely : the image is stored in the `storage/app/public/avatars` directory. The problem is the accessor : if I use a `dd($image);` before the return I can see the datas but it's not displayed in the html page

Comment: Is this a typo for the question? In your first return statement "return \response", if not this may be your issue.

I would also highly suggest not using your users ID as the file name, as anyone can inspect the element and retrieve the users unique ID in your database.

Comment: Yes You're right I modified the code for this.   For the moment I'm trying to make this code running, for the security I'll see later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to echo the Response facade like a string, however you just need to return the image path for the file.

You can use the url function on the Storage Facade to get the image path:

```
if($gravatar){
    $image = Storage::disk('local')->url('public/avatars/'.$gravatar.'.jpg');
    return $image;
}
```

Because you are using the value for the src:

```
src="{{ $user->gravatar }}"
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-urls

***Edit***

From the docs:

> Remember, if you are using the local driver, all files that should be
>   publicly accessible should be placed in the storage/app/public
>   directory. Furthermore, you should create a symbolic link at
>   public/storage which points to the storage/app/public directory.

Once this is done your returned url should display your image.

Comment: It's not working. It seems to be a better way cause I had `unknow` as source of the image and now I have `/storage/avatars/1.jpg`

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to add a symlink to the storage folder.

Comment: Ahahah great...thank you. i won't use Storage then but /public/ folder...How to kill a nice feature. ...

Comment: The feature should be fine to use, just run, `sudo ln -s ../storage/app/public storage` from your public folder and it should link to your storage folder at root